# CSS3 transition is not rendering overflow scoll properly

Tags: jquery, css, overflow, css-transitions

I'm using a transition on opacity in a tab plugin I'm building for my website. However, it's affecting the `overflow: auto` that I have on my div. Only the last one in the set is scrolling. This fiddle explains what I'm talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/ubbpbmfs/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="tab-content active" id="breeding">
        <h1>Breeding</h1>
        <p>Want to try your chances at getting a unique combination of two of the rabbits you own? Welcome to breeding! This takes place 
            in your habitat and heavily relies on the relationship of these two rabbits. Rabbits are genderless meaning you can breed 
            any two rabbits together, given you have the correct carrot item for it.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="adventure">
        <h1>Adventure</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed finibus dui tortor, eu fermentum libero condimentum hendrerit. 
            Duis efficitur faucibus varius. Suspendisse at turpis sit amet enim tincidunt tincidunt ac non urna. Praesent eget neque 
            gravida tellus lobortis aliqu.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="habitats">
        <h1>Habitats</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed finibus dui tortor, eu fermentum libero condimentum hendrerit. 
            Duis efficitur faucibus varius. Suspendisse at turpis sit amet enim tincidunt tincidunt ac non urna. Praesent eget neque 
            gravida tellus lobortis aliqu.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="gardening">
        <h1>Gardening</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed finibus dui tortor, eu fermentum libero condimentum hendrerit. 
            Duis efficitur faucibus varius. Suspendisse at turpis sit amet enim tincidunt tincidunt ac non urna. Praesent eget neque 
            gravida tellus lobortis aliqu.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="fishing">
        <h1>Fishing</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed finibus dui tortor, eu fermentum libero condimentum hendrerit. 
            Duis efficitur faucibus varius. Suspendisse at turpis sit amet enim tincidunt tincidunt ac non urna. Praesent eget neque 
            gravida tellus lobortis aliqu.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="change" data-content="breeding">Change content to breeding</a> | 
<a href="#" class="change" data-content="adventure">Change content to adventure</a> | 
<a href="#" class="change" data-content="habitats">Change content to habitats</a> | 
<a href="#" class="change" data-content="gardening">Change content to gardening</a> | 
<a href="#" class="change" data-content="fishing">Change content to fishing</a>
```

My CSS:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
}

    .content .tab-content {
        padding: 25px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        height: 150px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

        .content .active {
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('.change').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.tab-content').removeClass('active');

    $('#' + $(this).data('content')).addClass('active');
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`visibility` is your friend :)

The thing is, your last content is on top of everything and hence receiving all your mouse events and obviously blocking it for every other content under it. `opacity: 0` doesn't mean that the content is no more eligible for mouse events, it is actually still there. To make

Simply add `visibility: hidden;` as one more rule in the `.content .tab-content` rule and `visibility: inherit;` in the `.content .active` rule next to `opacity` and you are done.

Here is your updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubbpbmfs/2/)**.

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
}
.content .tab-content {
    padding: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content .active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: inherit;
}
```